# In Flutter app when app is in foreground ( app is close) then laravel api also call every 5, 10 mint

Tags: flutter, api, push-notification

In Flutter app when  app is in foreground ( app is close) then laravel api also call  every 5, 10 mint
And i don't want to use fcm,firebase or other  becasue my backend is in laravel

In Flutter app when  app is in foreground ( app is close) then laravel api also call  every 5, 10 mint
And i don't want to use fcm,firebase or other  becasue my backend is in laravel

Answer (score 0):

There's a good [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) for background/foreground service. Check if that helps, you can periodically call a program whilst the app is terminated or in background.

Comment: i try this package but not work when app close are in background

Comment: Recheck your implementation, or find/create an issue on their repository then. I've tried this plugin and had it working